# Denormalizing nested JSON object hierarchies in Jackson

Tags: java, json, jackson

Let's say I have a JSON object hierarchy like the following:

```js
{
    "name": "Mosquito Laser",

    "configurations": [{
        "currency": "USD",
        "price": "10.00" /* the Basic option */
    }, {
        "currency": "USD",
        "price": "50.00" /* the Pro option */
    }, ]

}
```

I would like to deserialize this json into a java object, and flatten it into a single level.  So for example, I would like to map the above json into the following java class:

```java
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class Product {

    @JsonProperty
    protected String name;

    protected String lowestPrice;
    protected String highestPrice;

}
```

I would like to use a custom method to compute the `lowestPrice` and `highestPrice` fields from the list of configurations in the json.  Assume for the sake of argument that the json hierarchy and the java object have been simplified here for clarity, and that in reality they are actually much more complicated so I do not wish to implement a completely custom deserializer.  I want most of the fields to be automatically deserialized using Jackson's databinding defaults, but I want to specify custom operations for certain fields.

Is there an easy way to tell Jackson to use a special method to compute the value of the `lowestPrice` and `highestPrice` fields automatically?

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
@JsonProperty("configuration")
@JsonDeserialize(using = ConfigurationDeserializer.class)
protected String cheapestPrice;
```

And a deserializer looks like this:

```
public class ConfigurationDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<String> {

    @Override
    public String deserialize(final JsonParser jsonParser, final DeserializationContext deserializationContext) throws IOException {
        (your logic to go from the configuration JSON to cheapestPrice goes here)
    }
}
```

Comment: Okay so this is a good solution, however I realized that I have an additional constraint that I didn't realize was important.  I actually need to compute MULTIPLE computed fields, not just one.  I'm not sure how to do that with this solution since computing the first field will swallow up the tokens in the streaming parser.  I'll update the question

Comment: @emmby I think then the only solution is to have a specific class for these two fields. Or use a Desierializer on your parent class.

Answer (score 2):

In ETL and SQL, this is aggregation.  A couple of questions:

- Do you need the values being aggregated?
- Do you need other values from lower level JSON?
- Is memory a concern?
- Is CPU a concern?

Comments:

- Aggregation requires saving state when parsing tree-like structures
- Fast streaming parsers don't save state
- State can either be passed into children or can be returned back from children.
- Jackson can be slow when parsing unneeded child values.

Comment: While this answer might provide some insight into resolving the OP's question, it is recommended to include some code samples demonstrating the concepts outlined in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

If all you need is to modify values just define getter method(s):

```
public class Product {
  public String name;

  protected String lowestPrice;
  protected String highestPrice;

  public int getLowestPrices() {
    return calculateLowest(lowestPrice);
  }
  // and similarly for highestPrice...
}
```

or, when reading JSON in, define matching setter. Methods have precedence over fields.